# How to find the first direct child element of a div

Tags: jquery

This should be easy but I am not able to do it.

I have a div element with id "LeftScrollableDiv" and I am trying to find the first child element under it:

```
$("#LeftScrollableDiv:first-child");

<div id="LeftScrollableDiv:first">
   <table></table>
</div>
```

But the result is null. Any help??

Comment: `$('#LeftScrollableDiv').children().first()`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ is your friend...

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
$('#LeftScrollableDiv').children().first();
```

[API](http://api.jquery.com/first//)

Answer (score 11):

```
$("#LeftScrollableDiv > :first-child");
```

Answer (score 4):

The `:first-child` checks if its **subject** is the first child of its parent. In thise case you are trying to select element with id `#LeftScrollableDiv` that is the first child of its parent. All the `:` selectors just filter previous selection, they don't select any new elements.

There is unfortunately no `.firstChild` method in jQuery so you must always select all the children first and then take out the first one.

A possible selector to do it is:

```
"#LeftScrollableDiv > :first"
```

[Which is far more efficient than `> :first-child`](http://jsperf.com/fristfirstfirst).

Answer (score 0):

The following didn't work for me:

```
$('#LeftScrollableDiv').children().first();
```

If you find the same, then you can treat the object returned by the children() method like an array.

To get the first element:

```
$('#LeftScrollableDiv').children()[0]
```

To get the last element:

```
$('#LeftScrollableDiv').children()[$('#LeftScrollableDiv').children().length-1]
```