# Need assistance on ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

this is my first time working with `$.ajax requests`, I am currently building a employee directory that should get 12 random people like this:

[image: Employee Gallery Mockup]

I created the 12 gallery cards dynamically, $gallery Markup represents each card

```
var $galleryMarkUp = $('<div class="card"> </div>');
  var $cardIMGContainer = $('<div class="card-img-container"> </div>');
  var $cardInfoContainer = $('<div class="card-info-container"> </div>');

  //Append $cardIMGContainer and $cardInfoContainer inside $galleryMarkUp
  $galleryMarkUp.append($cardIMGContainer, $cardInfoContainer);

  //I append an img src inside $cardIMGContainer
  $cardIMGContainer.prepend('<img class="card-img" src="https://placehold.it/90x90" alt="profile picture">');

  //I also need to append an h3 and a couple of paragraphs inside $cardInfoContainer
  $cardInfoContainer.prepend('<h3 id="name" class="card-name cap">first last</h3>',
  '<p class="card-text">email</p>', '<p class="card-text cap">city, state</p>');

//Append $galleryMarkUp inside <div id="gallery" class="gallery">
 $('#gallery').append($galleryMarkUp);
```

/*I used a loop to clone them 12 times
     */

```
for (let index = 0; index <11; index++) {
   $galleryMarkUp.clone().insertAfter($galleryMarkUp)
```

below is my ajax request I made to url: 'https://randomuser.me/api/?nat=us&results=12&'

```
$.ajax({
url: 'https://randomuser.me/api/?nat=us&results=12&',
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data) {
  console.log(data); //this should log the data for 12 employees in JSON format

  var employeeInfo = data.results //creating a reference to data.results

  $.each(employeeInfo, function(index, employee) {
    //create variable references for Name, email, city,state, etc
    var name = employee.name.first + " " + employee.name.last;
    var email = employee.email;
    var picture = employee.picture.large;
    var location = employee.location.city;
    var number = employee.phone;
    var fullStreet = employee.location.street + " " + location + " " + employee.location.postcode;
    var birthday =  employee.dob.date;

    //SHOW CONTENT FOR SMALL GALLERY CARDS

    //attach images to employee gallery 
    $('.card-img').attr('src', picture);

    //Get to display the name, I used a code snippet from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11468183/10043628 by user jagm
    $('.card-info-container > :first-child').text(name);

    //Get to display email
    $('.card-text').text(email);

    //Get to display city and state 
    $('.card-info-container > :nth-child(3)').text(location);



    //SHOW CONTENT FOR MODAL BOXES

    //display name
    $('.modal > :nth-child(2)').text(name);

    //attach images to employee modals
    $('.modal-img').attr('src', picture);

    //Display email
   $('.modal > :nth-child(3)').text(email);

   //Display city
    $('.modal > :nth-child(4)').text(location);

    //Display number
    $('.modal > :nth-child(6)').text(number);

    //Display address
    $('.modal > :nth-child(7)').text(fullStreet);

    //Display Birthday
    $('.modal > :nth-child(8)').text(birthday);  
  }); 
} 
});
```

so my question is, how do I add more employee cards without copying every single detail? I am currently able to get this:

[image: Every picture is the same]

also for reference, this is the repo of my project https://github.com/SpaceXar20/FSJS-techdegree-project-5, I have my ajax request on line 119 of app.js, could someone please help?

Comment: How and from where are you getting the content and populating the card?  You mentioned using ajax but I don't see any ajax request in your code.

Comment: Actually, the ajax call seems right could you check with the API method for issues.

Comment: You use json object from Ajax request and loop through that. Replace names and image url with the data from json. And cloning will not make it easy. You need to recreate every dog in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append your card template like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://randomuser.me/api/?nat=us&results=12&',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data); //this should log the data for 12 employees in JSON format

        var employeeInfo = data.results //creating a reference to data.results
        var _cardTemplate = '';
        $.each(employeeInfo, function (index, employee) {
            //create variable references for Name, email, city,state, etc
            var name = employee.name.first + " " + employee.name.last;
            var email = employee.email;
            var picture = employee.picture.large;
            var location = employee.location.city;
            var number = employee.phone;
            var fullStreet = employee.location.street + " " + location + " " + employee.location.postcode;
            var birthday = employee.dob.date;

            //SHOW CONTENT FOR SMALL GALLERY CARDS


            _cardTemplate += '<div class="card">';
            _cardTemplate += '<div class="card-img-container">';
            _cardTemplate += '<img class="card-img" src= "' + picture + '" alt="profile picture"></div>';
            _cardTemplate += '<div class="card-info-container"><h3 id="name" class="card-name cap">' + name + '</h3>';
            _cardTemplate += '<p class="card-text">' + email + '</p><p class="card-text cap">' + location + '</p>';
            _cardTemplate += '</div></div>';

            //SHOW CONTENT FOR MODAL BOXES

            //display name
            $('.modal > :nth-child(2)').text(name);

            //attach images to employee modals
            $('.modal-img').attr('src', picture);

            //Display email
            $('.modal > :nth-child(3)').text(email);

            //Display city
            $('.modal > :nth-child(4)').text(location);

            //Display number
            $('.modal > :nth-child(6)').text(number);

            //Display address
            $('.modal > :nth-child(7)').text(fullStreet);

            //Display Birthday
            $('.modal > :nth-child(8)').text(birthday);



        });

        $('#gallery').append(_cardTemplate); //Append Finally all cards with employee details
    }

})
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello Try below script

Demo Links: https://output.jsbin.com/wijaniwaxo

**You can check view source of above demo**

```
$(document).ready(function ()
        {
            var html;
            $.ajax({
                method: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: "https://randomuser.me/api/?nat=us&results=12",
                beforeSend: function ()
                {
                    $('.gallery').html('<h1 class="text-center">Please wait content loading...</h1>');
                },
                success: function (response)
                {
                    html = '';
                    if (response.results)
                    {
                        $.each(response.results, function (index, value)
                        {
                            html += '<div class="col-md-4 custom-col">';
                            html += '<img src="' + value.picture.medium + '" alt="Image ' + index + '" style="width: 100px;" />';
                            html += '<p>' + value.name.first + ' ' + value.name.last + '</p>';
                            html += '<p>' + value.email + '</p>';
                            html += '<p>' + value.location.city + '</p>';
                            html += '</div>';
                        });

                        $('.gallery').html(html);
                    }
                },
                complete: function (response){}
            });
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot